# what is MySQL.txt file?

Tags: mysql, windows

i have a very big file

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL.txt
```

it is about 12.2 GB 
what is this file? and should it be there?

because i could use such a space. :)

Comment: what kind of data is present inside it?

Comment: too big to open it with notepad but i found that it is MySQL.log and not MySQL.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A  MySQL log file holds all the transactions happening through MySQL.
As u mentioned its 12 GB I don't think so it will be easily handled by any software to read the contents inside it.You can delete it without affecting MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a "standard" MySQL file, look inside maybe it is a backup dump left there. However i think you can delete it without breaking anything.

Comment: too big to open it with notepad but i found that it is MySQL.log and not MySQL.txt